# strange behaviour of generalized lambda in c++14

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, c++14

To store a series of functions(of different types) and their identities in a same container, then call them by their identities, I first implement a generic lambda as a 'list' container, then pack the identity and the function body in a std::pair, and store the pair in a 'list';

the code for 'list' is

```
template< typename ... Args >
auto list( Args ... args )
{
    return [=]( auto func ){ return func( args... ); };
}
```

then define the 'cons' this way, to insert new pairs

```
template< typename List_1, typename List_2 >
auto cons( List_1 list_1, List_2 list_2 )
{
    return list_1( [=]( auto ... args_1 ){ return list_2( [=]( auto ... args_2 ){ return list( args_2..., args_1...); } ); } ); 
}
```

but unfortunately it seems this 'cons' generated 'list' cannot hold pairs correctly, see full code here:

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fo9tQnObFM4cyNcV

then I change the 'cons' a little bit, to

```
template< typename List_1, typename List_2 >
auto cons( List_1 list_1, List_2 list_2 )
{

    auto layer_1 = [=]( auto ... args_1 ) { return list_2(  [=]( auto ... args_2 ) { return list( args_1..., args_2... ); } ); };
    return list_1( layer_1 );
}
```

then it works, see here :

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GpXEkkfztdOxapIL

But these two 'cons' implementations are identical to me, can somebody please explain the problem?

EDIT:

following  Yakk's advice, I corrected the typo and trimmed the code to

```
template< typename ... Args >
auto list( Args ... args )
{
    return [=]( auto func ){ return func( args... ); };
}

#ifdef V1
template< typename List_1, typename List_2 >
auto cons( List_1 list_1, List_2 list_2 )
{
    auto layer_1 = [=]( auto ... args_1 ) { return list_2(  [=]( auto ... args_2 ) { return list( args_1..., args_2... ); } ); };
    return list_1( layer_1 );
}
#endif

#ifdef V2
template< typename List_1, typename List_2 >
auto cons( List_1 list_1, List_2 list_2 )
{
    return list_1( [=]( auto ... args_1 ){ return list_2( [=]( auto ... args_2 ){ return list( args_1..., args_2...); } ); } );
}
#endif

template< typename Func, typename List >
auto map( Func func, List the_list )
{
    return the_list( [=]( auto ... elems ){ return list( func(elems)... ); } );
}

#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream> 
int main()
{
    auto mfl = cons( cons( list( std::make_pair( std::string{"f1"}, [](int i){ return i; } ) ),
                 list( std::make_pair( std::string{"f2"}, []( double x, double y){ return x*y; } ) ) ),
                 list( std::make_pair( std::string{"f3"}, [](std::string s){ return s+s; } ) ) );

    auto pair_printer = []( auto the_pair ) { std::cout << "id:" << the_pair.first << "\n"; return the_pair; };
    map( pair_printer, mfl );

    return 0;
}
```

then tested the above code on clang++ v3.5 and g++4.9.2

using clang++ v3.5 with the first 'cons'(V1)

```
clang++ -o tmp tmp.cc -std=c++1y -lc++ -lc++abi -DV1
```

the output is correct :

```
id:f1
id:f2
id:f3
```

for the second 'cons'(V2)

```
clang++ -o tmp tmp.cc -std=c++1y -lc++ -lc++abi -DV2
```

the output is messy:

```
id:f1
id: 4S� 4S�
id:4S��4S��4S��S���
                            �S��
                                    84S��4S�
```

using g++ 4.9.2, both versions give expected output.

So is this a bug of clang++?

---

Updated years later: This strange behaviour has been corrected in the latest version (clang 6.0.1).

Comment: You interchanged the expansion order of the parameter packs. I.e. `args_2..., args_1...` vs `args_1..., args_2...`

Comment: I noticed the interchange, but the contents within args_2 and args_1 should not be modified; Here I noticed for the first 'cons', something within args has been modified.

Comment: Can you reduce to MVCE? Your test code that is, and make it explicit what you got and what you expect?  Have you tried this on more than one compiler? Does it still happen when you fix that typo? (I understand it should not matter, but check).  If you write cons that only works on one arg lists, does the problem go away? (ie, get rid of implicit `...` capture?)

Comment: Been a while.  The next thing I'd do is start creating some "noisy" types -- types that print out when they are destroyed, created copied and moved -- and see if we can track down things being destroyed.  Also note that gcc 4.9 uses non-standard compliant strings (cow strings): gcc 5.1 uses standard compliant strings.  Maybe gcc 4.9 is accidentally moving some data when it shouldn't?